# Convert string to int array C++

Tags: c++

How to convert string to int array in c++?
I am giving the input as

> 21 100 30

convert to an int array as

> 21,100,30

Comment: I was giving input in the program previously, but now i am trying to give input while running.

Comment: Google is your friend. This should be fairly easy to convert into c++ http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/4073-string-integer-array.html

Comment: yeah i had tried that but the input itself is given in array, my question was to convert from string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a similar thing for a TopCoder contest, I'll show you how I did it but won't guaranty that it's the best method.

To convert an string to int I used the function (you'll need #include sstream I belive)

```
int NtS ( string myS )
{
    istringstream buffer(myS);
    int value=0;
    buffer >> value;
    return value;
}
```

The above function will return a int from a string.
Now all you need to do is to split the initial string into smaller string.
For this I used this function

```
int getx(int x,string st)
{
    int nr=0;
    string ret="";
    for(int i=0;i<st.size();++i)
        {
            if(st[i]==' '){
                ++nr;
                continue;
                }
            if(nr==x)
                ret = ret + st[i];
        }

    return NtS(ret);
}
```

Where x is the number you want to get from the string. So if you want the first one you type 0. 
Example: If you want 100 from your string just write getx(1,"21 100 30"); and it will return 100 (int).

Now that you have this a simple for will convert you string into a vector.

```
for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
    myvector.push_back(getx(i,my_string));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your function NtS is also the same as the one liner `atoi(myS.c_str());`

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the info! Will use this from now on.

Comment: int main()
{
    std::string   line;
    std::vector<int>   lineData;
    std::stringstream  linestream(line);
    int value;
    while(lineStream >> value)
    {
            data.push_back(lineData);
    }
}